# Formatting Fortran complex number output for use in Mathematica

Tags: fortran

Here is a list that was orignially output from Fortran.

```
{{"(0.277336296055697, 0.120000000000000E+000)"}, 
 {"(-1.489297392708939E-002, 0.340000000000000E+000)"}}
```

which is to be interpreted as a list of two complex numbers.

Of course, *Mathematica* does not understand this, so, I would like to convert it into something like

```
{{0.277336296055697 + 0.12I}, {-0.01489297392708939 + 0.34I}}
```

Can I do this programmatically in *Mathematica*?

Comment: How did you "get" the array from Fortran to look like this in first place and have it land inside Mathematica? Was the data in file and you imported it into Mathematica?

Comment: Yes, I used "Import" to import a list of numbers outputted by Fortran.

Comment: You might be able to tweak `Import` directly, but you should provide the original data you import for that.

Comment: How did you use "Import"? Please provide example of the data in the file, and the command you used. M can import Fortran data http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ReadingTextualData.html

Comment: (0.277336296055697,0.000000000000000E+000)
 (-1.489297392708939E-002,0.000000000000000E+000)
This is the Fortran file "chi0.dat", all the complex numbers in a column. Now, in Mathematica, I import it by doing chi=Import["chi0.dat"];

Comment: (0.277336296055697,0.120000000000000E+000) (-1.489297392708939E-002,0.340000000000000E+000) actually, let's put a complex example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another one:

```
n = {{"(0.277336296055697,0.120000000000000E+000)"}, \
{"(-1.489297392708939E-002,0.340000000000000E+000)"}};

Complex @@@ ToExpression[StringReplace[Flatten[n], {"(" -> "{", ")" -> "}", "E" -> "*10^"}]]
```

> {0.277336 + 0.12 I, -0.014893 + 0.34 I}

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
data = {{"(0.277336296055697,0.120000000000000E+000)"}, 
        {"(-1.489297392708939E-002,0.340000000000000E+000)"}};
data = Flatten[StringCases[#, "(" ~~ x__ ~~ "," ~~ y__ ~~ ")"->{x, y}]&/@ a,Infinity];
Complex @@@ Partition[Internal`StringToDouble[#] & /@ data, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{"(0.277336296055697,0.120000000000000E+000)"}, {"(-1.489297392708939E-002,0.340000000000000E+000)"}};

Complex @@ (ToExpression /@ {StringDrop[First@#, 1], StringTake[Last@#, 5]}) &
    [Flatten@StringSplit[a[[#]], ","]] & /@ Range@Length@a
```

> {0.277336 + 0.12 I, -6.04833 + 0.34 I}

Comment: The second number does look suspicious...

Comment: @YvesKlett - It not only "looks suspicious" - it's simply "wrong" (was distracted by Suisse vs. Argentina). Will correct tomorrow.